# Matrix with trig functions and Cramer's rule

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, determinant

Using Cramer's rule solve for $x'$ and $y'$ in term of $x$ and $y$

$x = x'\cos\theta - y'\sin\theta\\
y = x'\sin\theta + y'\cos\theta$

So what I have is this

$\det\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta& -\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix} = \cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = 1$

Since the answer is one all the other determinants will be the final answers for the unknowns.

$x'= \det\begin{bmatrix}
x &-\sin\theta\\
y & \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix} = x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta$

$y' = \det\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & x\\
\sin\theta & y
\end{bmatrix} = y\cos\theta - x\sin\theta$

Is this correct?

Comment: Check my editing, and remove the unnecessary plus signs from some of the matrices' entries to add clearity.

Comment: And yes: it is right.

Comment: You can check the soluetion, plug in $x',y'$ in the system. Moreover, as $\det(A) \neq 0$ you know that the solution must be unique, so if it works that is it.